# Self-invoking named function compounds its results in .each loop

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check statuses of some applications. I have a self-invoking function that calls itself again during a .each method.  However, upon each successive call the results are exponentially multiplied.

Here is my html:

```
<table>
   <tbody id="applications">                    
        <tr>
            <td><b>Application 1</b></td>
            <td id="status" data-www="www.app1.com"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></td>
        </tr>                       
        <tr>
            <td><b>Application 2</b></td>
            <td id="status" data-www="www.app2.com"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></td>
        </tr>                       
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
(function checkStatus(){

    var app_table = document.getElementById('applications');
    var app_rows = $(app_table).find('tr'); 

    console.log('Row length: ' + app_table.rows.length);

    $(app_rows).each(function(index){                       

       var app_status = $(this).find('#status')
       var app_www = app_status.attr('data-www')

       var data_obj = {
         www: app_www
       }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/application-status/',
            data: data_obj,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(status){
               console.log('Status for ' + index + ' is ' + status);
               if(status){
                  app_status.find('i').css({color:'green'});                        
               } else {
                  app_status.find('i').css({color:'red'});
               }
             },
             complete: function(){                                                              
                setTimeout(checkStatus, 5000)
             }
            });                 
        })              
    })();
```

The first time it runs I get the correct output:

```
Row length: 3
Status for index 0 is true
Status for index 1 is true
Status for index 2 is true
```

However, the 2nd time it runs, I get:

```
Row length: 3
Status for index 0 is true
Status for index 1 is true
Status for index 2 is true
Row length: 3
Status for 0 is true
Row length: 3
Status for index 1 is true
Status for index 2 is true
Status for index 0 is true
Status for index 1 is true
Status for index 2 is true
Status for index 0 is true
Status for index 1 is true
Status for index 2 is true
```

The third time around is even worse.  Can someone explain what's going on?  Is it that my app_rows variable is not getting cleared?  I tried so many variations with my variables but I haven't been able to fix this. I'm new to jQuery.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: I believe ```success``` handler gets invoked twice (once for each tr) however, ```success``` handler then calls ```checkStatus``` which then sends off another 2 ajax request and the results start compunding

Comment: I didn't go through your exact issue, but one thing to keep in mind is that an id should only exist once per page. You have two elements with id="status". These should be changed to classnames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight alternative that you may want to try. I haven't tested this sorry

```
function setStatus(item, color) {
    item.css({ color: color });
}

function poll(url) {
    var data_obj = {
        www: url
    };

    return $.ajax({
        url: 'api/application-status/',
        data: data_obj,
        type: 'GET'
    });
}

function checkStatus(index, item) {
    var app_status = $(item).find('#status');
    var app_www = app_status.attr('data-www');
    var status_item = app_status.find('i');

    poll(app_www)
        .then(function(status) {
            var statusColor = status ? 'green' : 'red';
            setStatus(status_item, statusColor);
            setTimeout(function() {
                checkStatus(index, item);
            }, 5000);
        })
        .catch(function(status) {
            setStatus(status_item, 'red');
            setTimeout(function() {
                checkStatus(index, item);
            }, 5000);
        });
}

$(app_rows).each(checkStatus);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `setStatus` is being called *for each row*, which will then, *for each row*, call `setStatus` again. In a way, the code is like this:

```
function doSomethingForEachRow() {
    for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++){                                                                         
        doSomethingForEachRow()
    }
}
```

Because of this, the exponential branches are being created.